# Swipeable drawer in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got a problem with Swipeable drawer from Material UI. In normal Drawer isnt nessesary to add function onOpen. SO my question is what should I add thare?

```
            container={container}
            variant="temporary"
            open={mobileOpen}
            anchor="left"
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            onOpen={}
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as answered. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The "onOpen" is used for "opening" the drawer (its the behavior it will have when it opens)  If you want a persistent drawer (always open) there are other options there!
adding: Within the onOpen you should handle the change of value so react knows it is open and material ui make the transition.

https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#permanent-drawer

Good luck!